# Can't create a view using the views module

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-views

I created a view using Views module based on the default node index. But the first thing I found is this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1 OFFSET 0' at line 2

What might cause this and how do I solve it?

Comment: Enable the show SQL query from views settings and paste the complete SQL query see below the preview option. We can debug based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your SQL syntax !

View module just GUI for create query
so you be sure your choice was Logical for create a query